# how can I cluster texts without the number of categories?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster a few short texts without knowing the number of categories. Are there techniques and algorithms that can be used to implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short texts are very difficult to cluster even if you would know the number of clusters.

Because you have only very few words.

You won't be able to cluster this just by finding the right algorithm to call, but this will require a lot of tedious data integration.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. 
I want to try using hierarchical clustering, but I have no idea about its effect.

Comment: Doesn't work well on short sentences. "dog" and "doggy" are different words. You may as well just check if they have one word in common, or not.